Training GPT-2 on simple arithmetic data shows decreasing loss but the final model is rubbish. Any explanations?
So, I'm training a GPT-2 model on a simple task like for instance addition using the hugging face transformers library. During training the model shows that the train and validation loss are both decreasing, but when I test the model on either the train or validation data the model generates outputs that are less than 50% accurate (accuracy).

No matter what I've tried it seems that it's not working on this simple task and I don't know why when it's supposed to be something easy to learn?
